# how to create a french flag in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a french flag without using most of python's built in functions but for some reason my loop won't work... can anyone tell me why?

```
from PIL import Image
def french():
    flag= Image.new('RGB', (300, 200))
    pixels=flag.getdata()
    pixs= list(pixels)
    r=0
    w=100
    b=200
    while True:
        for x in range(r,(r+100)):
            pixs[x]= (255,0,0)
            flag.putdata(pixs)
            r=+300
        for x in range(w,(w+100)):
            pixs[x]= (255,255,255)
            flag.putdata(pixs)
            w=+300
        for x in range(b,(b+100)):
            pixs[x]=(0,0,255)
            flag.putdata(pixs)
            b=+300
        return (r>60000 or w>60000 or b>60000)
    flag.save('frenchflag.png')
french()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I see several things that *could* be a problem, but you need to be more specific that "doesn't work". What precisely do you expect, and what to you see instead?

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of

   ```
   # on first pass through the loop, exit the function and return False
   return (r>60000 or w>60000 or b>60000)
   ```

   I think you mean

   ```
   # when we are at the end of the pixel buffer, leave the loop
   if r >= 60000:
       break
   ```
2. Pixel-poking is a horribly inefficient way to create an image; use `PIL.ImageDraw` instead:

   ```
   from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

   RED   = (255,   0,   0)
   WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
   BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

   def french(fname, width=300, height=200):
       flag = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
       p, q = width//3, 2*width//3    # bar edge coordinates
       draw = ImageDraw.Draw(flag)
       draw.rectangle((0, 0, p, height), RED)
       draw.rectangle((p, 0, q, height), WHITE)
       draw.rectangle((q, 0, width, height), BLUE)
       flag.save(fname)

   french("frenchflag.png")
   ```

   which produces

   [image]